# Statistical probability of coin landing on second flip

Tags: statistics

A coin is flipped twice in a row. The first result is heads. Is the statistical chance of the coin landing on heads on the second flip 50 percent or 25 percent?

Comment: How can the first toss matter when you know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Each coin flip is an independent event, so the probability of the second flip would still be $\frac{1}{2}$ or $50\%$. I think you are confusing the probability of each flip being heads or tails and the probability that the two flips produce two heads in a row. The latter would be $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$.